# permutation test with a distribution of correct values

Tags: statistical-significance, classification, permutation-test

I want to test my classifier performance using a permutation test. I know how to test one actual value against a null distribution of values generated by randomly reassigning labels to my two classes.
However, in this case, I don't have one value but also a distribution of performances on correctly labelled data, because I perform the classification several times (to use slightly different, but overlapping, data and to split the data up in different ways for training/testing and cross-validation).

1. Is it enough to have one random relabelling for each classification that I do, so that I have an actual and a null distribution with 100 (or 1000) entries each? Or should I, for some reason, make a null distribution for each actual decoding performance?
2. How do I test whether my decoding is significantly better than the null distribution in this case?

Thanks!